# Программа для подбора пароля по хешу их crypt() выдаёт ошибочные пароли для проверки на соответствие хешу после перехода на четырёхзначные пароли

Tags: c, алгоритм

Писал код для взлома пароля с данным хешем. Написал циклы для взлома 3-х значного пароля, но когда добавляю еще один цикл для работы с 4-х значными паролями у меня из строки "A" сразу получается "A   +@". Вот код для 3-х значных

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    char key[8];
    char result[100],hash[100], salt[3];
    strcpy(hash,argv[1]);
    memcpy(salt, hash, 2);
    salt[2]='\0';
    int j = 0;
    char ch[8];
    ch[0]=' ';
    ch[1]=' ';
    ch[2]=' ';
        while (ch[2]<='z')
        {
            key[2]=ch[2];
            while (ch[1]<='z')
            {
                key[1]=ch[1];
                ch[0]='A';
                while (ch[0]<='z')
                {
                    key[0]=ch[0];
                    if (!strcmp(crypt(key,salt),hash))
                    {
                        printf("password is %s\n", key);
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //printf("%s, %d\n", key, j);
                    }
                    j++;
                    if (j>100000) return 1;
                    ch[0]++;
                }
                if (ch[1]==' ')
                {
                    ch[1]='A';
                }
                else
                {
                    ch[1]++;
                }
            }
            ch[1]='A';
            if (ch[2]==' ')
            {
                ch[2]='A';
            }
            else
            {
                ch[2]++;
            }
        }
    printf("No found\n");
}
```

И вот с добавленным циклом.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    char key[8];
    char result[100],hash[100], salt[3];
    strcpy(hash,argv[1]);
    memcpy(salt, hash, 2);
    salt[2]='\0';
    int j = 0;
    char ch[8];
    ch[0]=' ';
    ch[1]='\0';
    ch[2]='\0';
    ch[3]='\0';
    while (ch[3]<='z')
    {
        key[3]=ch[3];
        while (ch[2]<='z')
        {
            key[2]=ch[2];
            while (ch[1]<='z')
            {
                key[1]=ch[1];
                ch[0]='A';
                while (ch[0]<='z')
                {
                    key[0]=ch[0];
                    if (!strcmp(crypt(key,salt),hash))
                    {
                        printf("password is %s\n", key);
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%s, %d\n", key, j);
                    }
                    j++;
                    if (j>1000000) return 1;
                    ch[0]++;
                }
                if (ch[1]=='\0')
                {
                    ch[1]='A';
                }
                else
                {
                    ch[1]++;
                }
            }
            ch[1]='A';
            if (ch[2]=='\0')
            {
                ch[2]='A';
            }
            else
            {
                ch[2]++;
            }
        }
    ch[2]='A';
            if (ch[3]=='\0')
            {
                ch[3]='A';
            }
            else
            {
                ch[3]++;
            }
    }
    printf("No found\n");
}
```

Отличия двух кодов только в

```
    ch[3]='\0';
        while (ch[3]<='z')
        {
...
        ch[2]='A';
        if (ch[3]=='\0')
        {
            ch[3]='A';
        }
        else
        {
            ch[3]++;
        }
    }
```

С инпутом `./crack1 50sCm8faaj2LQ` по хешу находит пароль(LOPE) так как строка будет засорена. При работе с <4 знаками все нормально. Ошибку можно наблюдать после того, как начнется перебор 4-х значных паролей.

Comment: Если что, был фикс ошибки для коротких паролей. Код немного поменялся, но проблема осталась. Код отредачил.

Comment: запускал в cs50 lab